# How to Convert Mathml to ASCII code

Tags: android, ascii, mathml

i have checked many convertion tools but can anybody suggest me a

```
PAID OR FREE mathml to ASCII converter or any tool
```

to display mathematical equations in android `textView.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visit the solutions from www.wiris.com. With WIRIS editor you can convert from MathML to PNG images suitable to be displayed in any browser and in any application, in particular, also for android.

It is not clear what you mean by mathml to ASCII. As part of the accessibility solutions, the WIRIS tools can generate a textual representation of a formula. For example, for ½ the “ascii” version would be “1 over 2“.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. [Per the faq's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion), please be sure to disclose your affiliation *within* your response. (Otherwise it risks being flagged as spam by some)

Answer (score 1):

jqMath at http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html is a JavaScript library you can use.

Since it's in javascript, you can us a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to render it.

Comment: yes your are correct but my problem is i have around 10000 files of mathml prepared so i need a converter to convert it.